# Python: Cast int to double

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7

I am practicing calling matlab functions from python
and I am getting this error that I don't seem to understand how to fix.

Problem:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *=: 'double' and 'int'

This is my code:

```
import matlab.engine
mat = matlab.engine.start_matlab()

dims = mat.ones(1, 3)
dims *= 5 // here is the problem

print(dims)
```

I can assume that `ones` returns a double and 5 is int
    And this changes my problem to casting the int to double.

I tried using float(5) but then I get this:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *=: 'double' and 'float'

How do I cast an int to a double in python ?

Comment: use `5.0` instead of `5`

Comment: I already tried this 
I get this error again: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *=: 'double' and 'float'

Comment: Show the *entire* error trace.

Comment: What is `dims` before you try the `*=` is it a float type?

Comment: matlab does not support `*=` or other similar operations (`+=`...). Maybe you can not apply them from python either (on matlab processes). Try `dims = dims*5`, as silly as that might be.

Comment: @MarkRansom Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/untitled/hello_world.py", line 7, in <module>
    dims = dims*5.0
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'double' and 'float'

Comment: @MooingRawr that is all the code. Pretty simple. dims is a vector or ones. 
[1, 1, 1]

Comment: @mpaskov I changed it to dims = dims*5.0 still doesn't work.

Comment: @TonyTannous I was more or less asking if you can provide the `print type(dims)` but guess I will go install matlab

Comment: `dims *= matlab.double(5)` does it work?

Comment: @MooingRawr sorry m stands for dims, I changed m to dims and didn't change it in the print as the error wasn't there.

Comment: @Wasi no.
I get this error now.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/untitled/hello_world.py", line 7, in <module>
    dims = dims*matlab.double(5)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matlab\mlarray.py", line 51, in __init__
    raise ex
ValueError: initializer must be a rectangular nested sequence

Comment: `dims *= matlab.double([5])` what about this?

Comment: You could try to convert the `5` to a decimal object. from `import decimal` and use it like `dim *= decimal.Decimal(5)`

Comment: @MooingRawr
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *=: 'double' and 'Decimal'

Comment: @Wasi
It did cast it to double, however I get this error which is wierd
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'double' and 'double'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the MATLAB engine for doesn't support any of the python mathematical operators on data types it defines.  You can't even add two of MATLAB's own data types.

```
>>> matlab.double([[1]])+matlab.double([[1]])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'double' and 'double'
```

`double` in this exception is a MATLAB double, rather than the equivalent Python native type (which is `float`).

The only thing I could get to work consistently were numpy arrays:

```
>>> matlab.double([[1]])+np.array(1)
array([[2.]])
```

Note, however, that the result is an `array`.  That is a numpy data type.  So it would seem that MATLAB doesn't support numpy arrays either, but rather numpy arrays support MATLAB data types and will convert them to arrays.  That probably isn't what you want.

There is no reason this wouldn't be possible.  Python provides all the hooks to implement this sort of thing.  MATLAB just doesn't support it.

If you are unwilling to convert to numpy arrays, what you need to do is use the function versions of the MATLAB operators to do the calculations.  This is considerably more verbose, but works assuming you follow MATLAB casting rules:

```
>>> mat.times(dims, 5.)
matlab.double([[5.0,5.0,5.0]])
```

Unfortunately, adding integers to double matrices is not allowed in MATLAB at all (even in MATLAB's own interpreter), so you will need to use a float:

```
>>> mat.times(dims, 5)
MatlabExecutionError: Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.
```

The difference is that `5` in Python is an integer, while `5` in MATLAB is a double, so you won't see this error when using MATLAB unless you explicitly convert to an integer type.

You can also use the `eval` function to evaluate a symbolic expression, but first you need to load the variable into MATLAB:

```
>>> mat.workspace['dims'] = dims
>>> mat.eval('dims*5')
matlab.double([[5.0,5.0,5.0]])
```

It would also be theoretically possible to create a class that wraps the MATLAB classes and supports Python operations, but that is getting too complicated for this space.